# Querying related tables on Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables related with a one to many index. This is my first time in this scenario and im trying to figure out a nice and smart query to retrieve the data.

*Table name:* **questions**

*Structure*:

```
id poll_id question
```

*Table name:* **answers**

*Structure*:

```
id question_id answer
```

**question_id** from table *anwsers* is a forehing key of **id** on *questions* table.

I need to retrieve all the questions (and the respective answers options) given a **poll_id**. So far i have this query:

```
'SELECT * FROM polls_questions pq, polls_answers WHERE `poll_id` = ' . $pid
```

But the returned array is horrible inefficient, whit data repeated many times.

For a 4 questions poll i get 35 elements;

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [poll_id] => 1
            [question] => Domanda 1
            [atype] => 0
            [question_id] => 1
            [answer] => Risposta 1 domanda 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [poll_id] => 1
            [question] => Domanda 2
            [atype] => 0
            [question_id] => 1
            [answer] => Risposta 1 domanda 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [poll_id] => 1
            [question] => Domanda 3
            [atype] => 0
            [question_id] => 1
            [answer] => Risposta 1 domanda 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [poll_id] => 1
            [question] => Domanda 4
            [atype] => 0
            [question_id] => 1
            [answer] => Risposta 1 domanda 1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [poll_id] => 1
            [question] => Domanda 1
            [atype] => 0
            [question_id] => 1
            [answer] => Risposta 2 domanda 1 (F: Domanda 3)
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [poll_id] => 1
            [question] => Domanda 2
            [atype] => 0
            [question_id] => 1
            [answer] => Risposta 2 domanda 1 (F: Domanda 3)
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [poll_id] => 1
            [question] => Domanda 3
            [atype] => 0
            [question_id] => 1
            [answer] => Risposta 2 domanda 1 (F: Domanda 3)
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [poll_id] => 1
            [question] => Domanda 4
            [atype] => 0
            [question_id] => 1
            [answer] => Risposta 2 domanda 1 (F: Domanda 3)
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [poll_id] => 1
            [question] => Domanda 1
            [atype] => 0
            [question_id] => 2
            [answer] => Risposta 1 domanda 2
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [poll_id] => 1
            [question] => Domanda 2
            [atype] => 0
            [question_id] => 2
            [answer] => Risposta 1 domanda 2
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [poll_id] => 1
            [question] => Domanda 3
            [atype] => 0
            [question_id] => 2
            [answer] => Risposta 1 domanda 2
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [poll_id] => 1
            [question] => Domanda 4
            [atype] => 0
            [question_id] => 2
            [answer] => Risposta 1 domanda 2
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [poll_id] => 1
            [question] => Domanda 1
            [atype] => 0
            [question_id] => 2
            [answer] => Risposta 2 domanda 2
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [poll_id] => 1
            [question] => Domanda 2
            [atype] => 0
            [question_id] => 2
            [answer] => Risposta 2 domanda 2
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [poll_id] => 1
            [question] => Domanda 3
            [atype] => 0
            [question_id] => 2
            [answer] => Risposta 2 domanda 2
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [poll_id] => 1
            [question] => Domanda 4
            [atype] => 0
            [question_id] => 2
            [answer] => Risposta 2 domanda 2
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [poll_id] => 1
            [question] => Domanda 1
            [atype] => 0
            [question_id] => 3
            [answer] => Risposta 1 domanda 3
        )

    [17] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [poll_id] => 1
            [question] => Domanda 2
            [atype] => 0
            [question_id] => 3
            [answer] => Risposta 1 domanda 3
        )

    [18] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [poll_id] => 1
            [question] => Domanda 3
            [atype] => 0
            [question_id] => 3
            [answer] => Risposta 1 domanda 3
        )

    [19] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [poll_id] => 1
            [question] => Domanda 4
            [atype] => 0
            [question_id] => 3
            [answer] => Risposta 1 domanda 3
        )

    [20] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [poll_id] => 1
            [question] => Domanda 1
            [atype] => 0
            [question_id] => 3
            [answer] => Risposta 2 domanda 3 (F: END POLL)
        )

    [21] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [poll_id] => 1
            [question] => Domanda 2
            [atype] => 0
            [question_id] => 3
            [answer] => Risposta 2 domanda 3 (F: END POLL)
        )

    [22] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [poll_id] => 1
            [question] => Domanda 3
            [atype] => 0
            [question_id] => 3
            [answer] => Risposta 2 domanda 3 (F: END POLL)
        )

    [23] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [poll_id] => 1
            [question] => Domanda 4
            [atype] => 0
            [question_id] => 3
            [answer] => Risposta 2 domanda 3 (F: END POLL)
        )

    [24] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [poll_id] => 1
            [question] => Domanda 1
            [atype] => 0
            [question_id] => 4
            [answer] => Risposta 1 domanda 4
        )

    [25] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [poll_id] => 1
            [question] => Domanda 2
            [atype] => 0
            [question_id] => 4
            [answer] => Risposta 1 domanda 4
        )

    [26] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [poll_id] => 1
            [question] => Domanda 3
            [atype] => 0
            [question_id] => 4
            [answer] => Risposta 1 domanda 4
        )

    [27] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [poll_id] => 1
            [question] => Domanda 4
            [atype] => 0
            [question_id] => 4
            [answer] => Risposta 1 domanda 4
        )

    [28] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8
            [poll_id] => 1
            [question] => Domanda 1
            [atype] => 0
            [question_id] => 4
            [answer] => Risposta 2 domanda 4
        )

    [29] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8
            [poll_id] => 1
            [question] => Domanda 2
            [atype] => 0
            [question_id] => 4
            [answer] => Risposta 2 domanda 4
        )

    [30] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8
            [poll_id] => 1
            [question] => Domanda 3
            [atype] => 0
            [question_id] => 4
            [answer] => Risposta 2 domanda 4
        )

    [31] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8
            [poll_id] => 1
            [question] => Domanda 4
            [atype] => 0
            [question_id] => 4
            [answer] => Risposta 2 domanda 4
        )

    [32] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9
            [poll_id] => 1
            [question] => Domanda 1
            [atype] => 0
            [question_id] => 4
            [answer] => Risposta 3 domanda 4
        )

    [33] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9
            [poll_id] => 1
            [question] => Domanda 2
            [atype] => 0
            [question_id] => 4
            [answer] => Risposta 3 domanda 4
        )

    [34] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9
            [poll_id] => 1
            [question] => Domanda 3
            [atype] => 0
            [question_id] => 4
            [answer] => Risposta 3 domanda 4
        )

    [35] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9
            [poll_id] => 1
            [question] => Domanda 4
            [atype] => 0
            [question_id] => 4
            [answer] => Risposta 3 domanda 4
        )

)
```

I can solve this just using two queries, one for the questions and one for the answers and this will give me two arrays, but doing that there is no point for relationship between tables. How can I query the database and retrieving question and answers on an optimal way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not joining the tables on any columns so you are getting a cartesian result set:

```
'SELECT * 
FROM polls_questions pq
INNER JOIN polls_answers pa
  on pq.id = pa.question_id 
WHERE `poll_id` = ' . $pid
```

You should be using `JOIN` syntax where you join the tables on the question id. This is make sure that you will only return the questions with the answers.  Otherwise you are returning each question with every answer.

I used an `INNER JOIN` between the two tables which will return the matching rows between both tables.  If you wanted to return all questions even if there was no matching row in the answers, then you would need a `LEFT JOIN`.

If you need help understanding join syntax, here is a great [visual explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
'SELECT * 
FROM polls_questions pq, polls_answers 
WHERE `poll_id` = ' . $pid . ' AND pq.id = polls_answers.question_id'
```